# In a RegEx with multiple subexpressions (i.e. using parenthesis), how do I know which one it matched?

Tags: regex

So, for example:

```
//The string to search through
var str = "This is a string /* with some //stuff in here";

//I'm matching three possible things: "here" or "//" or "/*"
var regEx = new RegExp( "(here)|(\\/\\/)|(\\/\\*)", "g" );

//Loop and find them all
while ( match = regEx.exec( str ) )
{
    //Which one is matched? The first parenthesis subexpression? The second?
    alert( match[ 0 ] );
}
```

How do i know I matched the "(//)" instead of the "(here)" without running another regex against the returned match?

Comment: If you want to know which part of regexp match - you should split your regexp into three different regexp and check each of them.

Comment: @hadvig, that's not always possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which group is defined:

```
var str = "This is a string /* with some //stuff in here";    
var regEx = /(here)|(\/\/)|(\/\*)/g;

while(match = regEx.exec(str)){
    var i;
    for(i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        if(match[i] !== undefined)
            break;
    }

    alert("matched group " + i + ": " + match[i]);
}
```

Running at http://jsfiddle.net/zLD5V/

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I was getting thrown off because I was thinking of zero based so I was starting with match[ 0 ] and it wasn't working so I figured it was some other property.

Comment: @Don, `match[0]` is the whole match.